# Dynamically added listbox event is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My problem is when I click on one listbox another list box should be displayed with dynamically related values. The listbox is displayed but the listbox event is not firing. The `lb_SelectedIndexChanged` event is not firing.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select EmpId,EmpName from OrgChart where      ManagerID=0", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        int i=0;

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            empid[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
            ename[i] = dr[1].ToString();
            i++;
        }

        for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(empid[j]+"-"+ename[j]);

        ListBox1.Items.Add("create new");
    }
}

protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Table1.Visible =false;
    Table2.Visible = false;
    string comand = ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    if (comand == "create new")
    {
        Table1.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Table2.Visible = true;
        string[] emp = comand.Split('-');
        getdetails(Convert.ToInt32(emp[0]));
    }
}

static ListBox lb = new ListBox();           
void getdetails(int empid)
{
    managerid = empid;
    con.Open();
    com = new SqlCommand("select EmpId,EmpName from OrgChart where ManagerID=" + managerid + "", con);
    dr = com.ExecuteReader();

    lb.ID = "lb1";
    lb.AutoPostBack = true;

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        lb.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString() + "-" + dr[1].ToString());
    }

    lb.Items.Add("create new");

    lb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.lb_SelectedIndexChanged);

    this.Controls.Add(lb);
}

void lb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Table1.Visible = false;
    Table2.Visible = false;
    getdetails(managerid);
    string comand = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedValue.ToString();
    if (comand == "create new")
    {
        Table1.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Table2.Visible = true;
        string[] emp = comand.Split('-');
        getdetails(Convert.ToInt32(emp[0]));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need set the **`.AutoPostBack`** property to true.

In your code sample is like

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   //...
   ListBox1.AutoPostBack = true;
   //...

}
```

Comment: Or from GUI you can edit the property of the listbox to `TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

add your list oninit event because some events won't initiate with onload event